React Query Use Mutation Is Being Called Twice
So i am using react-query to do a simple post request to my api the problem I have is that the same request is being called twice. I know this because the console.log statement in the code below is being called twice how do i fix this problem?
`  export default function Home() {
const global_http = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
const mutation = useMutation(
  {
    mutationFn: async () => {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post(global_http + "users/");
      return response.data;
    },
    onSuccess: (data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    onError: (error: any) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
  }

);

useEffect(() => {
  mutation.mutate();
}, []);

if (mutation.isPending) {
  return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
}

return (
  <>
    <h1>This is our home page</h1>
    <p>This cannot be accessed until the user is logged in!</p>
  </>
);

}`
So far, i have looked into the documenation, and the format of the request is same, I do not understand why it is being called twice this happens not only in this mutation but also in all of the other requests that I do which are not called in useEffect

This is because effects are executed twice in strict mode during development. This doesn't happen in production, so it's most likely not a problem.

Can you please share the useQuery() configuration used at the provider level

Why are you using a mutation? Your use case looks more like a query from the small code sample.
